# Django: How to display the average of all rating using django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am creating a function where users can rate a book using django, i have achieved the part where users can rate the book using a form from the front end and it get saved in the backend. Now what i want to achieve is a way to display an average of all the rating that the user make. e.g let say there are `usera - 1.0`, `userb - 3.0`, `userc -5.0`. i want to display the average which is `3.0` and i dont know how to achive this. let men put some of the code i have written below

models.py

```
USER_BOOK_RATING = (
        ("1.0", "★☆☆☆☆ (1/5)"),
        ("2.0", "★★☆☆☆ (2/5)"),
        ("3.0", "★★★☆☆ (3/5)"),
        ("4.0", "★★★★☆ (4/5)"),
        ("5.0", "★★★★★ (5/5)"),
)

class BookRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=USER_BOOK_RATING)
    review = models.TextField()
```

view.py - only what i am doing is listing out all the reviews but not the average of star rating

Comment: Is that average the one per book?

Comment: @DavidLu yes, it is one per book

Comment: Can you provide *USER_BOOK_RATING* values

Comment: If you want numerical average, you should start by using numerical values and not strings. Why do you use `CharField` instead of integer or float field for rating?

Comment: The django docs explains how to do aggregations like average etc.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django annotate Avg of foreign model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741736/django-annotate-avg-of-foreign-model)

Comment: @HåkenLid becuase i could add `choices='...'` using charfield, i don't know if that can be achived using integerfield

Comment: `choices` works with all field types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'd use a `DecimalField` instead of a `CharField` - you can't really do mathematical operations on a string. This would look something like:

```
from decimal import Decimal

USER_BOOK_RATING = (
        (Decimal("1.0"), "★☆☆☆☆ (1/5)"),
        (Decimal("2.0"), "★★☆☆☆ (2/5)"),
        (Decimal("3.0"), "★★★☆☆ (3/5)"),
        (Decimal("4.0"), "★★★★☆ (4/5)"),
        (Decimal("5.0"), "★★★★★ (5/5)"),
)

class BookRating(models.Model):
    # rest of model as before
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, choices=USER_BOOK_RATING)
```

Once you've changed that, you can use `aggregate` and `Avg` - something like:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

# Get average score of all books
average = BookRating.objects.aggregate(avg=Avg('duration'))
# Returns a dict - if using Decimal fields you'll get something like:
# {'avg': Decimal('3.81818181818182')}
```

Add your filtering before the `aggregate` call and hopefully that should get you close to the solution you're looking for.

You may also want to look at [django-star-ratings](https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings) - a library we wrote at work because we kept needing to implement star ratings. Not sure if it's an exact fit - it doesn't have reviews - but it looks close to what you want to achieve, or at least you can see the source for inspiration.